# sum of columns with condition in python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
id_command  command_status  stage   line_amount global_amount
61  ZeFMAA1 Pending     582.96  582.96
61  UbUjNAAV    Pending     70481.00    582.96
945 0bR8hEQAS   Pending     6400.00 12800.00
```

I would like to add a new column "decision" which is a boolean value (true or false)
True if global_amount of a command is greater than 30% of the sum of line_amount     of a command, and false if is not .

Can you help me to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: What is expected output from your sample data? Or which answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on :

> sum of line_amount of a command

Use [`df.groupby()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group on the `id_command` and use `transform` to get sum distributed on each row. Then multiply by `0.3` and compare by [`series.gt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html):

```
df['decision']=df.global_amount.gt(df.groupby('id_command').line_amount.transform('sum')*0.3)
print(df)
```

---

```
   id_command command_status    stage  line_amount  global_amount  decision
0          61        ZeFMAA1  Pending       582.96         582.96     False
1          61       UbUjNAAV  Pending     70481.00         582.96     False
2         945      0bR8hEQAS  Pending      6400.00       12800.00      True
```

Comment: thanks anky_91, but why you and @jezrael have different results? :o

Comment: @cyrinepersonne the other result Jez calculates row by row, and this one calculates based on the sum of line amount taking id_command as a group.

Comment: I believe your answer is correct, but rather wait for OP clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['decision'] = df['global_amount'].gt(df['line_amount'].mul(.3))
print (df)
   id_command command_status    stage  line_amount  global_amount  decision
0          61        ZeFMAA1  Pending       582.96         582.96      True
1          61       UbUjNAAV  Pending     70481.00         582.96     False
2         945      0bR8hEQAS  Pending      6400.00       12800.00      True
```